# batch xcopy invalid parameters

Tags: batch-file

what i am trieing to do is to copy files from specific locations. The problem is xcopy tells me that I have invalid parameters. Due to the fact I never made a batch program before, I wanted to ask if it is possible to make it like that?

```
set _pfadTarget = path\test


set _pfadSourceDesk = c:\Users\xxxx\Desktop
set _pfadSourceDocu = c:\Users\xxxx\Documents


set _propertyDOC = \*.doc


REM -------ALL DOC Files--------
set _FullSourcePath = %_pfadSourceDesk%%_propertyDOC%
set _FullDestPath = %_pfadTarget%%_propertyDOC%
xcopy %_FullSourcePath% %_FullDestPath% /s /y
set _FullSourcePath = %_pfadSourceDocu%%_propertyDOC%
xcopy %_FullSourcePath% %_FullDestPath% /s /y

exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces around the equals breaks this, and it looks like all your variables are affected.

```
set _FullSourcePath = %_pfadSourceDesk%%_propertyDOC%
```

This method fixes the variable name, and the surrounding double quotes allow long file and path elements in the variable contents, like spaces.

The quotes below in the top line aren't actually included in the variable when used this way, so the quotes are used again in the Xcopy command to protect the contents.

```
set "_FullSourcePath=%_pfadSourceDesk%%_propertyDOC%"
xcopy "%_pfadSourceDesk%%_propertyDOC%" "d:\my backup\2014 04 28\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```